# trying to rename folders in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /ad /b /S "*-ABC*"') DO (

    REM Get the foldername without the path name and without the extension (i.e. Folder1-ABC)
    SET "eir_foldername=%%~na"
    echo "!eir_foldername!"

    REM Remove "-ABC" from the filename (i.e. Folder1)
    SET "reg_foldername=!eir_foldername:-EIR=!" 
    echo "%%~dpa" "!reg_foldername!"    

    rem for /D /r %%~dpa!reg_foldername! in (*) do rmdir /q /s %%~dpa!reg_foldername!
    for /D /r %%i in (%%~dpa!reg_foldername!) do echo %%i

    Rename "%%~dpa" "!reg_foldername!"
    REM Rename the file (with full path and filename) to the new filename (that does not have "-Eir" in it + the original extension)   
)
)

echo Successfully renamed!
rem Endlocal

Endlocal

pause

:end
```

I have a path which contains various folders with the same name. For example, in the pash `C:/Test/First/Second/`, I have folders `Folder1`, `Folder1-ABC`, `Folder2`, `Folder2-ABC`.

What I am trying to do is to remove the folders without `-ABC` and rremove `-ABC`  if a folder name contains it, for example `Folder1-ABC` should become `Folder1`).

Comment: You can take certain parts of variables using `%varname:~details%` (https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html). In your case you could extract the last 4 digits of variables and see if they are equal to "-abc" with `%var:~-4%`

Comment: Please read the tag info rather than assigning some random tags...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr /i /v "\-ABC$"') do (
    if /i exist "%%~A-ABC\" (
        echo rd /q /s "%%~A"
        echo move "%%~A-ABC" "%%~A"
    )
)

pause
```

With paired folder names i.e. `name` and `name-ABC`, you are looking for the latter name and removing `-ABC` from the name. It would be perhaps be easier to append `-ABC` than to remove `-ABC`.

`findstr` with `/v` will print lines that do  not match `-ABC` at the end of line, due to use of `$` anchor. Now each path processed in the loop appends `-ABC` to `%%A` to check if the paired name does exist. If it does, then the `rd` and `move` commands will execute.

The `echo` command infront of `rd` and `move` are for testing. If satisfied is OK, remove the `echo` commands.